# Dynamic array data in Highcharts

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am passing dynamic array data to pie chart in high chart. Want to know how dynamic data is passed to drill down.

```
series:[{
          data:[{
                   name:finalarrayname(array which contains data names),
                   y:finalarrayvalue(array which contains data value),
                   drilldown:'fruits'
                }]
       }];
```

I'm using above snippet code to display pie chart of dynamic array data but chart is not loading.

Chart will be loaded if I use below code

```
series: data:finalarrayvalue
```

Comment: The object inside the data array has incorrect structure. The object represents a single point so properties like name or y should be single values as well (not an arrays) - see documentation for better understanding https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Comment: Thanks to your response...Got ur point but i need to pass dynamic array data to drilldown.How can i do that?

Comment: Pass the array and when you want to change it, use dynamic methods for updating charts/series such as chart.update(), series.update(), series.setData(), etc. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.update

Comment: I need to pass array data to y axis in data.How can i do that?

Comment: You cannot change data by changing y axis. You can change data with the methods I listed in the previous comment. Read the links I pasted, see the examples from the links. If you have a problem, create a live example on jsfiddle like this http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-update/